# jquery function to increment font sizing for accessibility task

Tags: jquery

just trying to write a jQuery function that will increment all the p tags font sizing when it's called. I've done this so far...

```
$("#incfont").click(function() {            
    $('p').each(function(){
        var fontsize;
        fontsize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
        $(this).css({'font-size':(fontsize+1)+'px'});
    })
})
```

It seems to increment the font once but not any calls after that.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S8gHN/1/

Comment: maybe you just need to add a `$(document).ready(function () {});` to your javascript?

Comment: it can be simplified a lot to ` $("#incfont").click(function () {
     $('p').css('font-size', '+=1')
 })` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S8gHN/5/

Comment: Yes, I have the ready function around it.

Comment: @EricRobinson since it is working once I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Im just speculating since the jsfiddle that @ArunPJohny posted worked.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for your feedback, that is a nice way to consolidate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that intermediate var or function; see [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value).

```
$("#incfont").click(function() {
    $('p').css('font-size','+=1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this,

I need to parseFloat() not parseInt the extracted font size from each element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fontsize;
$("#incfont").click(function() {

                $('p').each(function(index){
                    if(index==0){
                    fontsize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
                    }
                    $(this).css({'font-size':(fontsize+=1)+'px'});

                })
            })
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yLgCB/

Answer (score 0):

this would be another way: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/6yxBV/1/)

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
var p = $("p")[0];
  if (p.style.fontSize == "") {
    p.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }

  p.style.fontSize = parseFloat(p.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}
```