# How would one go about implementing A and a clickable links to make text larger and smaller to follow good accessibility/usability practices?

Tags: html, css

I have seen many examples of sites using A and a clickable links which reduces or increases the size of text within a web page.

However, I confused when I looked at the source code even though it appears this is possible through HTML.

Could someone please provide me with a good method to do so.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19969045/1113766

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:

```
  <a onclick="size++; document.getElementById('body').style.fontSize = size;">BIGGER</a>
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work. You should make two links, first with size++, then with size--. Don't forget to initiate the variable size in the head:

```
<script>
  var size = 15;
</script>
```